# Working with django-pagedown

Tags: python, django, markdown

I am following the instructions on the official [Django-pagedown repo](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown)

1. `pip install django-pagedown` - installed without errors
2. `Add pagedown to your INSTALLED_APPS` - error thrown is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pagedown'

   3.Collectstatic run smoothly.

When I check the modules currently in my virtual env using `help('modules')`, pagedown was not present, but in my global installation of python, it was present, so my question is, why can't my project work/use the present installed django-pagedown installation? what am I missing here?

python - 3.6.4

django version - (2, 0, 4, 'final', 0)

pip version - 10.0.1

os - windows

Comment: activate the `virtualenv` before installing the package

Answer (score 1):

The package is actually installed in your computer, as you can see it presents in the global installation. Just because you didn't activate the virtual environment that you use.

Go to your project, activate the virtual environment (`scripts\activate`).
Make sure that you see the name of your `virtualenv` shown before the path like that `(env_name)C:\Users\....`

Then run `pip install django-pagedown`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem and it was pip, somehow while running the command `pip install django-pagedown` in my IDE, (and running in my virtual env), it was installing pagedown globally and missing in my virtual env, so, I just changed IDEs and that's it. Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If the package is installed globally, and the virtualenv is setup such that it doesnt look into your global packages, then this issue can occur.

You need to either install the package using the pip command after activating the virtualenv or maybe run the project without the virtualenv ( in this case you will also need to have other dependencies to be installed globally)